# Why I can't transfer string after transferring image file from python client to java server?

Tags: java, python, sockets

My goal is to transfer string data after transferring image file from python client to java server.

I can successfully transfer only string data between java server and python client but when I add image file transfer code between string data transfer code my code gets stuck or gets null value.

in short I can't send string data from java server to python client and from python client to java server after transferring image file from python client to java server.

My java eclipse version is 2018-12 (4.10.0) and python version is python 3.

1.JAVA server code

```
package socket_test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class socket_test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ServerSocket server = null;

        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(8000);
            Socket client = server.accept();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            client.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"
                    )
            );
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);

            String message_1 = br.readLine();
            System.out.println(message_1 + "\n");

            pw.print("Server: Hello");
            pw.flush();

            String message_2 = br.readLine();
            System.out.println(message_2 + "\n");

            pw.print("Server: I am good");
            pw.flush();

            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\eclipse-workspace\\socket_test\\img\\1.jpg");

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int len = 0;
            while ((len = dis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            fos.close();
            // after this I can't transfer string data anymore.. when i use pw.print then code gets stuck and message_4 gets null.

            String message_4 = br.readLine();
            System.out.println(message_4 + "\n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            server.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

2.Python client code

```
from socket import *
from select import select
import sys

HOST = '' # sorry it is my ip
PORT = 8000

client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

image = '/home/pi/Downloads/1.jpg'

try:
    client.connect((HOST,PORT))

    client.sendall(bytes("Client: Hello", encoding = 'utf8'))
    client.sendall(bytes("\n", encoding = 'utf8'))

    reply = client.recv(1024)
    reply = reply.decode()
    print(reply, "\n")

    client.sendall(bytes("Client: How are you?", encoding = 'utf8'))
    client.sendall(bytes("\n", encoding = 'utf8'))

    reply = client.recv(1024)
    reply = reply.decode()
    print(reply, "\n")

    img = open(image, 'rb')
    converted_img = img.read()
    client.sendall(converted_img)
    img.close()

    client.sendall(bytes("Client: See you again", encoding = 'utf8'))
    client.sendall(bytes("\n", encoding = 'utf8'))

    client.close()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: You have implemented a protocol. Your protocol on the client side sends a file of unknown length, followed by "Client: See you again\n". However, on the server side at this point in the protocol you read until EOF and write the contents out to `1.img`. I think you'll find that this file also contains the  "Client: See you again\n" as the last part of it. You need a better protocol, perhaps by sending an 8-byte file length in bytes before sending the file. That way the server can read the length of file as a Java long and then know exactly how many bytes to read in.

Comment: you mean client should let server know exactly how many bytes server should read before receiving image file? if so is it possible to let server know by adding some codes to my code?

Comment: Yes, but you have to modify both the client and server code.

Comment: I fixed it. I modified byte[] buffer = new byte[4096] to byte[] buffer = new byte[1] and then I made loop stopped when the rest bytes is 17 (I think string bytes is 17 because when I use other numbers, message_4 has null again) even though It takes more time to receive a image file in comparison with using new byte[4096], I can fixed it thanks to your advice. thank you.